# Admob adViewDidReceiveAd won't work in TableViewCell

Tags: swift, admob, tableview

I have an Admob banner in a TableView cell. Everything seems to be working, but when I try to get the `func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!)` to work. This is my code so far:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Ad_Cell", for: indexPath) as! Native_Ad_TableViewCell

        cell.bannerView.adUnitID = "xx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        cell.bannerView.rootViewController = self
        cell.bannerView.load(GADRequest())
        cell.bannerView.delegate = self

        return cell
}
```

In my tableviewCell:

```
class Native_Ad_TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        bannerView.isHidden = true
    }

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
        bannerView.isHidden = false
        print("Ad Loaded")
    } 
}
```

`func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!)` won't be called at anytime even when I know the ad has loaded. Does somebody knows a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If `func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!)` is not called, please check the size of the frame of your `GADBannerView`. Your frame should not be equal to `.zero`, I have recently had the same issue as you.

If your bannerView has a frame, check the size in your AdManager account. The size should be exactly the same has your bannerView's frame.

For testing, you can test with this AdUnitId: `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716`
[More AdUnitId here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads#sample_ad_units)